# Don't understand this part of code from "Programming: principles and practice using C++", chapter 6 by Bjarne Stroustrup

Tags: c++, class, token

I've been learning C++ using "Programming: principles and practice using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup, and I've been stuck on chapter 6 for 1 week now. I've been searching for an explanation, but even those explanations I couldn't understand. I only know the basics of classes from YouTube. The book hasn't gone there yet.

Here's a part of the code from the book (`calculator002.cpp`):

```
class Token 
{
public:
    char kind;
    double value;
    Token(char k) :kind{ k }, value{ 0.0 }{}
    Token(char k, double v) :kind{ k }, value{ v }{}

};

//Token t1{ '+' };
//Token t2{ '8',11.5 };

const char number = '8';


double term();

double primary();


class Token_stream
{
public:
    Token get();
    void putback(Token t);
private:
    bool full{ false };
    Token buffer{ 0 };
};


void Token_stream::putback(Token t)
{
    if (full) error("putback() into a full buffer");
    buffer = t;
    full = true;
}

Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) {
        full = false;
        return buffer;
    }

    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;

    switch (ch) {
    case ';':
    case 'q':
    case '(': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':       // let each character represent themselves
        return Token(ch);
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {
        std::cin.putback(ch);
        double val;
        std::cin >> val;
        //std::cout << val << '\n';
        return Token{ '8',val };
    }
    default:
        error("Bad Token");
    }
}
```

In `Token_stream`, why is it `bool full{false}` instead of `full = false`?

In `Token_stream::get()`, why does the `char` I input turn into a `double`? How does that work?

The book really doesn't explain much, or maybe I'm too slow at understanding, but there's a lot I don't understand.

Comment: Look up uniform initialization.

Comment: *why is it bool full{false} instead of full = false* These two do the same thing. Ignore it for now. Just remember, `type name{value};` is the same as `type name = value;` (*almost always, but not quite*, but ignore it for now).

Comment: *In Token_stream::get(), why do the char I input turn into a double?* It doesn't quite do that. What this code does is the following. (1) Let's read a character. (2) Is it a letter or plus or minus or... ? OK use that character. (3) But what if it's a digit? Oooh, it is a beginning of a number! We've just destroyed that number by chipping off its first digit! What to do? What to do? OK let's quickly put that character back and pretend we have never read it and don't tell anyone. Tell `std::cin` that there's a number there, and ask it to read that number for us.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245967/discussion-on-question-by-zean-dont-understand-this-part-of-code-from-programm).

Answer (score 2):

> In Token_stream, why is it bool full{false} instead of full = false?

Either would work in this case.  Among other differences, the brace initialization disallows so-called "narrowing conversions" (from larger types that don't fit in the destination type), so is arguably safer in some cases.  Like if you said `bool full = 7`, that would compile, but possibly indicate a bug in the code because it's a weird thing to write.  `bool full{7}` will not compile.

> In Token_stream::get(), why does the char I input turn into a double? How does that work?

It doesn't.  `cin >> val` reads a whole, possibly multi-character number from standard input.  The only problem is that you've already consumed the first character of the number to decide it's a number in the switch statement.  So `cin.putback` just undoes the effect of the `cin >> ch` above the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Token_stream::get(), why does the char I input turn into a double? How does that work?
```

After you create the char variable 'ch', the first character of your input is read into 'ch' as a 'char'.

```
char ch;
std::cin >> ch;
```

**'cin >>' can read inputs from the stream into different types such as char, int, double, etc.** In this case, 'cin >>' is taking the first character from the stream and reading it into the 'char' variable 'ch'. If the input (character from the stream) was a number, you would be able to read it into an 'int' or 'double' (cin >> [int/double variable]) as well as a char.

When you read that character from the stream (**cin >> **) and into a variable, the character is taken out of the stream and is no longer available to be read. [Here is a description of reading from and putting back into a stream](https://medium.com/@namantam1/how-to-use-cin-get-cin-peek-and-cin-putback-in-c-programming-73aad118c4ed).

Next comes the switch statement.

```
switch (ch) {
case ';':
case 'q':
case '(': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':       // let each character represent themselves
    return Token(ch);
```

If 'ch' is one of the following symbols [ ; , q , ( , + , etc. ], the 'char' will be used to make a token and that token will be returned.
**'ch' does not need to be put back into the stream since it has been "tokenized" and will not need to be read again from the stream.**

```
case '.':
case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
{
    std::cin.putback(ch);
    double val;
    std::cin >> val;
    //std::cout << val << '\n';
    return Token{ '8',val };
}
```

Next, if 'ch' is one of the following symbols [numbers or a decimal] a few things happen.

1. **cin.putback(ch)** puts 'ch' is put back into the stream.

   This is done because the program do not know if the number is just one character or has multiple digits or a decimal. Once 'ch' is put back into the stream, it is available to be read by 'cin >>'. **Remember that 'cin >>' can read different data types (char, int, double, etc).**
2. Next a double 'val' is created. **cin >> val** reads the next item from the stream into 'val'. If we had not done **cin.putback(ch)** two lines earlier, the first character (number) would be missing from the stream. If the number has multiple digits or a decimal, **cin >> val** will read all of the numbers and decimals into 'val'.
3. Now that we have read the stream into a double 'val', we can "tokenize" 'val' and return it. Once 'val' has been "tokenized", it is not longer needed in the stream.

It took me a while to understand this as well. I hope this helps.